# Mathematica and GAP: Is there an interface?

Tags: interface, wolfram-mathematica, gap-system

Although the Abstract Algebra Add-on is a beautiful package for Mathematica, imo there is nothing that beats [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/), at least not for Group Theory. When I looked at Sage a few years ago, I found that said to have an interface with Mma but when I looked at it closer it turned out to be somewhat primitive ( but operational ). I know that work has been done at the Technical University of Eindhoven ([OpenMath](http://www.openmath.org/software/index.html)) on a platform for integrating / interfacing the major math tools, I even started to work on it. But that work got lost. Now to my question:

**Is there, does anyone have, and are you willing to share, an interface between GAP and Mathematica?**

Comment: @Sjoerd nice edit I made a while back. <:-o

Comment: @mr.wizard It was late tonight. Please forgive me if I appear slow. To which edit are you referring?

Comment: I created the grammatical error you corrected.  See the edit history for the full story.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One options is to use [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) as an intermediate. Sage can interface both with [Mathematica](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/sage/interfaces/mathematica.html) and [GAP](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/sage/interfaces/gap.html).
I believe that Sage interfaces with both programs by:
a) running their console interfaces in the background using [pexpect](http://wiki.sagemath.org/pexpect)
b) knowing how to translate most of the GAP and Mathematica syntax into its native syntax.

Note that I've done this a couple of times before and it works ok - but it means you don't get to use the Mathematica notebook interface....

A really useful tool would be to hook Mathematica up to [expect](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/expect/info) (or [pexpect](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/)) so that similar interfaces to console programs can be written for Mathematica. This is basically what the second quote in Sjoerd's answer is suggesting.

Comment: I found the work that has already been done on the issue at http://www.openmath.org/software/index.html , but I think it the project has died. Maybe I should pursue from there.

Comment: @nilo There is [Pythonika](http://code.google.com/p/pythonika/) for interfacing with Python.  It might make it easier to use pexpect.  I looked at how Pythonika works the other day, and it does not inspire trust (e.g. uses and removes Global` variables and looks messy in general), but it does function.  Also, pexpect seems to be Unix-only.

Comment: Thanks. @Simon and ( Szabolics ). I'll investigate further, since I'll be doing another course in Group Theory next year, I might work on a the Mathematica / GAP Interface myself. With all your expert advice this should be doable.

Comment: @nilo: A solid GAP/Mathematica interface would be great. I can see myself using such a thing, so I'll be glad to try to help (if I have time!)

Comment: @Simon, Noted, and thanks. I'll get back to you on this in the next two weeks.

Comment: @nilo: I'll be on holiday and not checking SO. Then I'll be crazy busy writing up a couple of papers. So take your time...

Answer (score 7):

The [GAP FAQ](http://www.gap-system.org/Faq/Programming/programming1.html) seems to be rather pessimistic about this:

> 8.1: Can I call GAP functions from another programme?
>
> **The short answer is no**. To explain a little more fully, essentially
> all the algebraic functionality of the GAP system is written in the
> GAP language, and so needs the GAP interpreter to run. The interpreter
> is written in C, but does not coexist happily with other code in the
> same process for a number of reasons, so there is no sensible way to
> link GAP into a C, Java or other program as a subroutine library.

There is some hope, though:

> **What you can do** is to run GAP in a child process and communicate with
> it using pipes, pseudo-ttys, UNIX FIFOs or some similar device. We
> have done this successfully in a number of projects, and you can
> contact the support list for more detailed advice if you want to go
> down this route.

**Update**

The FAQ now also reads:

> Relatively recently, some of the SAGE developers have produced libGAP, which allows the entire GAP system to be embedded as a C library. One still can't embed individual functions by themselves though and the first call to libGAP still has to invoke the full GAP start-up sequence.
>
> Alternatively, there are a number of ways of running GAP as a server process and calling it from C of C++ programs. See the SCSCP package for the GAP side. There are several C and C++ libraries that implement the client side.

Comment: I came as far as that, a few years ago. I used a Java program as an intermediary. ( The code is on a PC which needs repair. ) From and to GAP you can only read and write strings. http://www.openmath.org/software/index.html did a lot of work on the issue but I think that project died.

Comment: Ideas of OpenMath found further use in the [SCIEnce project](http://www.symcomp.org/). The linked page contains a list of systems supporting SCSCP protocol, and both GAP and Mathematica implementations are there.

Comment: In the meantime, the GAP FAQ quoted in the answer has been updated a little: please see [here](http://www.gap-system.org/Faq/faq.html#8.1).